# модификаторы доступа top level classes

Tags: java

Не нахожу информацию, какие могут использоваться модификаторы доступа для top level classes?

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то [плохо искали](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).

Для "top level classes" - public и default. Public - виден за пределами пакета. Default (вообще без модификатора) - виден только в пределах пакета.

Для членов класса добавляются модификаторы protected (виден только внутри объявляющего поле (метод) класса и его наследников) и private - виден только внутри объявляющего поле (метод) класса.